# Is there any usage for ' * ' in C else than multiplication and pointer?

Tags: c

Is the any more use of `*`, but for pointers `*p` and multiplication `a*b` ? If yes what usage it has?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Do note that it is used both in declarations to declare pointers, and in expressions to dereference pointers. Although both are "for pointers", it's important to understand the difference.

Comment: An asterisk is also used in `printf()` format strings with an argument to specify field width.

Comment: It’s used in `scanf()` conversion specifications to suppress assignment.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's part of multi-line comment syntax `/*insert comment here*/`

Comment: ... and character constant `'*'`, and part of a _string literal_ `"*"`